# Why do I get error 401 when I query items of user?

Tags: node.js, relationship, http-status-code-401, strongloop, loopback

In the StrongLoop API Explorer I have the option to query:

> /People/{id}/food_prefs

Person is based on the built in User model. This query should return a JSON list of all the food_prefs for that Person (User). Instead I get a 401 error about authorization.

The model relations are thus:

```
Person has many food_prefs
food_pref belongs to Person (foreign key: personId)
```

food_pref model looks like this:

```
property: type : number
property: personId : number
```

When I send a request to Person/{id}/food_pref I get an error 401:

```
{
  "error": {
    "name": "Error",
    "status": 401,
    "message": "Authorization Required",
    "statusCode": 401,
    "code": "AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED",
    "stack": "Error: Authorization Required\n
}
```

I've not yet set up any ACL's, but even when I do set it up for access to everyone, I still get this error. Why?

Comment: You first need to authenticate your identity before making requests to the API. Include the session Id returned for authentication in requests.

Comment: I tried that, I got the authentication token and set the token in explorer, still no luck. Same error.  It's weird because I can do a query on the opposite, /food_prefs/{id}/person and get the user ID and e-mail info for the person who owns that food_pref.

Comment: Also I did slc loopback:acl and set person to everybody has access for all methods and even that didn't do the trick.

Comment: What about the base user model acl ? Have you tried to changed them to see if it impacts your child model ?

Comment: In a much simpler model I tried adding  this to the person.json under common/models   {
      "accessType": "EXECUTE",
      "principalType": "ROLE",
      "principalId": "$everyone",
      "permission": "ALLOW",
      "property": "_get_toys"
    } which worked but it did not work for _get_food_prefs, I'm wondering if the property is named something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to add the following permissions to the ACL section in the Person model. The file name is common/models/person.json:

```
{ "accessType": "EXECUTE", 
  "principalType": "ROLE", 
  "principalId": "$everyone", 
  "permission": "ALLOW", 
  "property": "__get__foodPrefs" 
}
```

Similar properties can be set for other methods such as those you use to extend the model, for example a remote method called "getList" set in common/models/person.js.  You would simply replace __get__foodPrefs with getList.  Be sure to note that the auto generated methods such as the one above has two underscores not one.

Also, other permissions can be $authenticated, $owner, etc..